# sftp using camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to use sftp using camel, and getting jsch esception. 
The route that I created for the SFTP -

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring">
    <package>myGroupId</package>
    <route>
      <from uri="file:src/srcData?noop=true"/>
      <choice>
        <when>
          <xpath>/person/city = 'London'</xpath>
          <to uri="file:src/targetData/UK"/>
        </when>
        <when>
          <xpath>/person/city = 'Chicago'</xpath>
          <to uri="file:src/targetData/US"/>
        </when>
        <when>
          <xpath>/person/city = 'Tokyo'</xpath>
          <to uri="sftp://XXXserverXXX:22/dir1/subdir?username=testUser?password=testPwd&amp;binary=true"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
          <to uri="file:src/targetData/OT"/>
        </otherwise>
      </choice>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

But with this configuration I am facing the following exception - 
 **com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey:**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably define a hostfile:
The "knownHostsFile" option should point to a ssh known hosts file with the public key of the host you are connecting to in it.

It's actually documented over here: http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html